# Pointer initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I've seen many questions about pointer initialization but I couldn't find answer for something that bothers me recently a lot.  Why does it work on gcc :

```
class C {
};

/* other stuff here */

typedef C* pTypeC;
C* pOtherTypeC = pTypeC(0);
```

Is it valid to use "(0)" on typedef to initialize pointer with NULL ?

Comment: I am not sure (hence this is a comment and not an answer), but I think it is interpreted as: `C* pOtherTypeC = (pTypeC)(0);` which is equal to `C* pOtherTypeC = (C*)(0);` Leaving you with a cast.

Comment: in C++11 you can/should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` anyway

Comment: @awoodland: Why should? Not necessarily. If you don't care about those extra type safety checks you may as well use just 0...

Comment: Unfortunately, my app can use only C++03 standard.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Why wouldn't you care about type safety? >:|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that pTypeC(0) is considered as a casting operation.

```
C* pOtherTypeC = (pTypeC) (0);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's initialising a `C*` to a `C*` which was initialised to `0`. It's perfectly legal, but you should prefer `C* blah = nullptr`, though both do about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `NULL` can be defined a couple different ways. Sometimes it can simply be assiging the value `0` to a pointer at which point there is an implicit conversion from an integral to pointer type, other times it's defined with a cast such as `(void*)0`, allowing it to be converted to any other pointer type, but failing should you explicitly assign it to a non-pointer type, and in C++11 there is a specific global `nullptr` object you can use to initialize a pointer with a "NULL" value.

In general though, how you're initializing your pointer is confusing, and is not a recommended coding practice.  Just explicitly assign either `nullptr` or `NULL` to the pointer, and if you choose `NULL`, then make sure to include `<cstddef>` if you haven't included any other header files so you don't get compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't initialization of an object, you haven't allocated any new memory or created any new objects -- you're assigning a pointer to `NULL` (which is equal to the integer value `0`).

Working backwards:

```
C* pOtherTypeC = pTypeC(0);
C* pOtherTypeC = pTypeC(NULL);
C* pOtherTypeC = C*(NULL);
C* pOtherTypeC = (C*) NULL;
C* pOtherTypeC = NULL;
```

All five lines are functionally equivalent and will produce the same result.

Comment: fixed to be clear the initialization refers to the class `(C *)` object... though my reply was beat by 1m or so.